# Kafka offset management: enable.auto.commit vs enable.auto.offset.store

Tags: python, apache-kafka, librdkafka

A Kafka Consumer by default periodically commits the current offsets unless it is turned off by disabling `enable.auto.commit`. According to the documentation you're then responsible for committing the offsets yourself. So when I want **manual** control, that seems to be the way to go, however the [documentation](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/INTRODUCTION.md#at-least-once-processing) also mentions the *stored* offsets and that if you want manual control you should disable `enable.auto.offset.store` and use `rd_kafka_offsets_store()` and leave the auto-commit untouched.

Can somebody explain why the latter approach is to be preferred? Disabling auto-commits should have the exact same effect?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

With `enable.auto.commit=true` librdkafka  will commit the last stored offset for each partition at regular intervals, at rebalance, and at consumer shutdown.

The offsets that are used here, are taken from an in-memory offset store. This store will be updated automatically when `enable.auto.offset.store=true`.

If you set `enable.auto.offset.store=false` you can update this in-memory offset store by yourself via `rd_kafka_offsets_store()`.

This is preferred over disabling `enable.auto.commit` because you do not have to reimplement calling commit at regular intervals yourself, but can rely on the already built-in logic instead.

You have *manual control* about whether or not offsets are committed either way, but disabling `enable.auto.commit` and calling `commit` yourself will most likely lead to more frequent commits.